# Node isn't working in console

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, mongodb, chat

I'm watching some tutorials on youtube, how to make a real time chat with node.js from [phpacademy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkXQEwHn2nA&index=6&list=PLfdtiltiRHWHZh8C2G0xNRbcf0uyYzzK_) channel.

Now I'm in the step where I should run my server.js file in console. I'm running it in console with command

> node server.js

When I run it, nothing happens, just a whitespace. It should output a message like "info - socket.io started".
It works when I change the script to something like "console.log("worked");".

[Click here for an image.](http://www.part.lt/img/0d0a86aa9e5ce2c48ecdfefde842a5f7906.jpg)

MongoDB is running perfectly and had no errors till now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no errors because there are not any errors. Everything is working perfectly but you don't know that. That's why it is a good practice to log on which port is the server running.
For example add in the end of server.js:

```
console.log('Server running on port: 8080');
```

You could even move the port in a variable :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080 ;

console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
```

Comment: Ok, now I continued to watch the tutorial. I included javascript dependency as he did in tutorial at 2:20. Then he opened inspector on localhost in the webpage and clicked on the network tab. There was socket.io running in the network tab. In my website there's nothing like socket.io.is, just main.css file. And when I write the code in the console as he does i got an error: "ReferenceError: io is not defined". More help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your code ? And link to his tutorials ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWHZh8C2G0xNRbcf0uyYzzK_ . I'm at part 4 of his tutorials.
Code: http://pastebin.com/2QrW9NX4 and http://pastebin.com/eQC2XVtA

Comment: If you want you can add me in skype so I can see better what is your problem - svetla_venci1 , write here when you send a request :)